# Blender Eevee render is fine. Cycles messes up my mesh!

Tags: rendering, mesh

[image]

This is what its supposed to look like (Eevee)

[image]

Huge Lighting improvement. that's what I like. But now The floor has bloated up! (Cycles)

I Think the it might be the material screwing with things or maybe my UV placement.

i import my textures from CC0 using lily surface scraper.

its weird because the pillars are fine just the floor doesn't want to accept the texture

IDK

It Seems no one else is having this problem

Please help

**I Will include the BLEND file!**

[image]

Comment: This is pretty common. You need to lower the displacement node scale

Comment: @Gorgious How would I do that? Do you have an example?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRilLLyyn1Y&list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6&index=16&ab_channel=Blender

Comment: As Gorgious said, take a look at the floor material, there's a Displacement node plugged into the Material Output, it creates these bumps, so either lower down its value or unplug it